# Reading mf4 data through asammdf and getting unexpected data structure

Tags: python, data-analysis, mdf, post-processing, asammdf

I am relatively new to python and am trying to do some data post-processing through it. I am using the `asammdf` library to read an `mf4` file. I can perfectly open it with `NI DIAdem`, therefore I know that the data is in there.
Unfortunately, in Python the data structure looks very weird, it seems to me like there is only one timestamp for each channel. I suspect that I am missing something in how I should import mf4 files with asammdf, but being relatively new to the library I am a bit clueless at the moment. Can anyone help?

Code to import the file is simply:

```
mdf = MDF('FileName')
```

The structure of the data can be seen in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIP2X.png)

Comment: How does one view the structure of the data as per the attached screenshot in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `get` or `select` to extract the signals from the measurement

```
m = MDF('filename')
altitude = m.get('Altitude_WGS84')
print(altittude, altitude.samples, altitude.timestamps)
```

See the documentation https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#mdf4

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @danielhrisca ! I have been trying to do it the way you proposed, unfortunately it seems to me like Python is not able to recognise the samples, in fact when I print I get the following[1]. Looking at the structure, the following[2] appears :\  

 

[1]: https://imgur.com/glwAnOZ
[2]: https://imgur.com/ndB6sTA

Comment: I can't say exactly why there are no samples. It would help if you could send a demo file to my email